# WPF application using .cs

Tags: c#, wpf

I am still relatively new to C# and programming in general, so I'm not sure if I'll even be able to ask this question properly, but here goes. I'm currently taking a class for C# using Visual Studio specifically, and the assignment that we were given is to use a WPF application that the teacher provided, and then create a .cs file to input our code to make the application run properly. I have been successful in creating console applications, as well as WPF applications that only used VB, but I'm not entirely sure how to make these two concepts work with each other.

So far my code looks as follows:

MainWindow.xaml (Instructor provided):

```
<Window x:Class="CreateClassesObjs.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CreateClassesObjs"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164" IsDropDownOpen="True"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Select this course" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="283,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="166" Click="button_Click"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="69" Margin="66,233,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="164"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Please select a course " HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="383"/>
    <Label x:Name="label1" Content="You have selected these courses:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,202,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="176"/>

</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs (Instructor Provided):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CreateClassesObjs
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    Course choice;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Course course1 = new Course();
        Course course2 = new Course();
        Course course3 = new Course();
        Course course4 = new Course();
        Course course5 = new Course();
        Course course6 = new Course();
        Course course7 = new Course();

        course1.setName("IT 145");
        course2.setName("IT 200");
        course3.setName("IT 201");
        course4.setName("IT 270");
        course5.setName("IT 315");
        course6.setName("IT 328");
        course7.setName("IT 330");



        this.comboBox.Items.Add(course1);
        this.comboBox.Items.Add(course2);
        this.comboBox.Items.Add(course3);
        this.comboBox.Items.Add(course4);
        this.comboBox.Items.Add(course5);
        this.comboBox.Items.Add(course6);
        this.comboBox.Items.Add(course7);
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        choice = (Course)(this.comboBox.SelectedItem);
        this.listBox.Items.Add(choice);
    }

}
}
```

And Course.cs (The code that I have started working on):

```
#region Using directives
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
#endregion
namespace CreateClassesObjs
{
public partial class Course :MainWindow
{
    //Field
    private string courseName;

    //Method to set courseName to string value
    public void setName(string newName)
    {
        courseName = newName;
    }

    //overrides string ToString
    /*public override string ToString()
    {
        // this method returns the name field
        Course course1 = new Course();
        Console.WriteLine(course1.courseName);

    }*/
}
}
```

I've been trying to piece this together from what tutorials I could find, but I feel like I'm just confusing it. I'm not looking for a complete answer, but a nudge in the right direction. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why does `Course` inherit `MainWindow`?

Comment: I hope this course isn't intended to teach anyone WPF... the instructor's code just made me die on the inside.

Comment: @SLaks Like I said, I wasn't really sure what to do. I saw that it was setup like this in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file, and I was trying to do something similar, but Visual Studio auto-completed MainWindow instead of Window, and I didn't catch it before submitting this. Do I even need to inherit anything for this file?

Comment: @Guttsy Thank you for your help. The focus of this class is simply C#, and we have barely touched on WPF, hence my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You're really close to having this working. You just need to change your `ToString` method. I'm guessing you're currently seeing something like this:

[image: example]

If you're not seeing this because you cannot compile, I'd suggest making a new .cs file for your Course object instead of having it wedged into your `MainWindow` class. There's *no reason whatsoever* for a `partial` class here.

WPF currently doesn't know how to display a course in the ComboBox. In a *normal* WPF application, one would define a DataTemplate to tell the ComboBox how to present a Course. Thanks to the abomination created by your instructor, we don't have that luxury. Instead, you need to return something in your `ToString` method to appease it. I'll let you figure out what that is.

(Please note: this is a prime example of how NOT to do WPF, even at an introductory level. Not your fault by any means.)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, but here is how I was able to get the program to function. You need your getters and setters defined and your new Course to print out something.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CreateClassesObjs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        Course choice;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Course course1 = new Course("IT 145");
            Course course2 = new Course("IT 200");
            Course course3 = new Course("IT 201");
            Course course4 = new Course("IT 270");
            Course course5 = new Course("IT 315");
            Course course6 = new Course("IT 328");
            Course course7 = new Course("IT 330");

            course1.setName("IT 145");
            course2.setName("IT 200");
            course3.setName("IT 201");
            course4.setName("IT 270");
            course5.setName("IT 315");
            course6.setName("IT 328");
            course7.setName("IT 330");

            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course1);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course2);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course3);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course4);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course5);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course6);
            this.comboBox.Items.Add(course7);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            choice = (Course)(this.comboBox.SelectedItem);
            this.listBox.Items.Add(choice);
        }

        class Course
        {
            private string name = "";


            public Course(string name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public void setName(string name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }

            public string getName()
            {
                return name;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return getName();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreateClassesObjs
{
    class Course
    {
        private string ClassName { get; set; }

        public void setName(string selection)
        {
            ClassName = selection;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ClassName.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

They are still using this at the school because I am in the same boat.  I got it to work off of the suggestions on here.  The best suggestion I can make is that if anyone else finds this topic, leave feedback with the school about it.  That's the only way that the course can change to teach us properly.